# Convert string to Date in ios by cordova problem

Tags: ios, cordova

I want to convert this string "2018-11-13T9:24" to Date in my js Code

```
var date = new Date('2018-11-13T9:24');
app.dialog.alert(date, 'Date');
```

but in my alert, I see:

[image: Alert Image]

I don't have any problem with time after 10 like '2018-11-13T11:24'

Comment: Try `new Date('2018-11-13T09:24:00');` and see if the problem persists

Comment: Date Format should be `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ`
In your case, it is 9:24, and it should be 09:24